# Regex that matches two sentences varying by one word

Tags: regex, match, pcre

I am looking for a regex that will match both of these examples:

`Hello I am really him.`

`Hello I am him.`

In general, how do you set up a regex that matches both a string, and a subset of that string that is missing a word?

**Update**:

So this was just an example sentence to see if I could reproduce the same pattern on my actual string. This didn't quite work however, so here they are.
I need to match the sentence:

`Ulcerative colitis patient, biopsy taken from the descending colon, macroscopic inflammation vissible`

where the word `descending` may or not be there, and the word `no` might appear after the last comma. So it  might be:

`Ulcerative colitis patient, biopsy taken from the descending colon, macroscopic inflammation vissible`

`Ulcerative colitis patient, biopsy taken from the descending colon, no macroscopic inflammation vissible`

`Ulcerative colitis patient, biopsy taken from the colon, macroscopic inflammation vissible`

`Ulcerative colitis patient, biopsy taken from the colon, no macroscopic inflammation vissible`

Comment: Something like `Hello I am(?: really)? him.`

Comment: I don't understand this post. I thought you were using the original example as a template of sorts, not the verbatim text, spacing and caps of a huge literal sentence.  Nothing is that static in text !! You'd be better off using a few word literals interspersed with `.*?` to get matches.

Comment: @sln For the most part it is static. The only thing that changes is the presence (or not) of the words `descending` and `no`

Comment: If it's for a single sentence then that's fine, but if it's for many different sentences, you have a tough row to hoe.

Comment: Note typo: "vissible" should probably be "visible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hello I am (\w*\s?)him.
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/4QRJDx/1)

Edit after the question update with the actual string and all the test cases:

`Ulcerative colitis patient, biopsy taken from the(\s?\w*\s?)colon,(\s?\w*\s?)macroscopic inflammation vissible`

These can be verified at the following regex101 link: [regex101.com/r/4QRJDx/3](http://regex101.com/r/4QRJDx/3)

Comment: Will this work again? For example, to match `Hello I am him.` , `Hello I am really him.` , and `Hello I am really him again.` 
Could the regex be `Hello I am (\w*\s?) him (\w*\s?).` Because that doesn't seem to work when I test it on my sentences.

Comment: No, of course my solution wouldn't work if the missing word is at the end of the sentence. I didn't get also this test case from your question

Comment: @KyleWeise you should invert \w and \s in the second case. Try this: `Hello I am (\w*\s?)him(\s?\w*).`  I updated the regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/4QRJDx/2 and it matches also the additional test case

Comment: @KyleWeise `Ulcerative colitis patient, biopsy taken from the(\s?\w*\s?)colon,(\s?\w*\s?)macroscopic inflammation vissible` ... link to verify: https://regex101.com/r/4QRJDx/3

Comment: In the regex debugger, yes. but for some reason not in my code. I'm still fiddling with it. This is a good direction though thanks

Comment: This also matches "Hello I am Joachim." Consider changing `\s?)` to `\s)?`.

Answer (score 3):

For this example, you would want to use "?" to denote an optional item. Also, you'll want to use "()" to make more than a single character optional at the same time.

Here's the regular expression (exact syntax may differ slightly based on your program):

```
/Hello I am (really )?him/
```

Example syntax with egrep:

```
echo "Hello I am him" | egrep "Hello I am (really )?him"
echo "Hello I am really him" | egrep "Hello I am (really )?him"
```

Example syntax with sed:

```
echo "Hello I am him" | sed "s/Hello I am \(really \)\?him//"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the word 'really' and the following space optional:

```
/Hello I am (?:really )?him\./
            ^         ^           group
             ^                    non-matching
                       ^          make the whole group optional
                           ^      escape the '.' so it only matches a literal '.'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6bZNbJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers cover the most obvious and natural reading of the question.

But for interest's sake, another interpretation might be: how to match a sequence of two sentences, the second of which has at most one word missing, compared to the first?

In that case, you're looking at something like:

```
(\w+\b\s*)*?(?:\w+\b\s*)(\w+\b\s*)*[.?!]+\1\2[.?!]
```

Three sequences of words (zero or more; one; and zero or more); sentence-ending punctuation; then only the first and last word sequences.

Efficiency could probably be improved, though.